# Revoke google play game services permissions programmatically

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm using google play game services in my app. The one thing that bothers me is that when the user signs out and later back in again, he is not asked to approve the access anymore.

This is my sign out method, pretty much from the examples:

```
public void signOut() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        // nothing to do
        debugLog("signOut: was already disconnected, ignoring.");
        return;
    }

    // for Plus, "signing out" means clearing the default account and
    // then disconnecting
    if (0 != (mRequestedClients & GameHelper.CLIENT_PLUS)) {
        debugLog("Clearing default account on PlusClient.");
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
    }

    // For the games client, signing out means calling signOut and
    // disconnecting
    if (0 != (mRequestedClients & GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES)) {
        debugLog("Signing out from the Google API Client.");
        Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
    }

    // Ready to disconnect
    debugLog("Disconnecting client.");
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

After this, the app is still connected as I can see in the google settings app. The next time I call `mGoogleApiClient.connect();`, it connects automatically without asking the user again.

Is there a way to either completely disconnect the app programmatically, or another way to have google play game services ask the user for permission the next time I connect?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: Is `clearDefaultAccount` actually being called? Your debugLog is printed?

Comment: Yes, both `Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount()` and `Games.signOut()` are executed.

Comment: I assume you sign in code is more or less the same as in the documentation as well? Nothing stands out to me. You can try [manually invalidating their token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) with a HTTP request. It should revoke their access.

Comment: Hmm, besides that this solution looks pretty dirty, I'm not really sure where to get the correct token since i'm not using the API directly. Only through GoogleApiClient